# Renderização de templates com blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Meu problema está na hora de renderizar desse trecho abaixo:
A parte: `@include('admin::layouts.includes.footer')` fica fora da div#wrapper, alguém saberia me dizer porque e como faço para que fique dentro?

layout.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    @include('admin::layouts.includes.header')
    @include('admin::layouts.includes.navigation')

    <!-- Main Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        @yield('content')
        @include('admin::layouts.includes.footer')
    </div>
</div>
```

Conteudo do `@include('admin::layouts.includes.footer')`

```
<!-- Footer-->
<footer class="footer">
    <span class="pull-right">
        {{ __('Por') }} <a href="https://www.mauricioschmitz.com.br" target="_blank">Mauricio Schmitz</a>
    </span>
    {{ config('app.name', '') }} 2017-<?php  $date = new \DateTime(); echo $date->format('Y');?>
</footer>
```

HTML renderizado visualizado no inspect

```
<!-- Main Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper" style="min-height: 570px;">
        <div class="content">    
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <span class="pull-right">
            Por <a href="https://www.mauricioschmitz.com.br" target="_blank">Mauricio Schmitz</a>
        </span>
        SGQ TOTAL 2017-2017</footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Posta o código completo do `@include('admin::layouts.includes.footer')` também.

Comment: Teu `@yield('content')` tem conteúdo ou é vazio? Se tiver algo verifica se não tem nenhuma `div` a mais sendo fechada sem ter sido aberta.

Comment: Poxa, valew  @DarleiFernandoZillmer, vacilo meu... não tinha nem pensado nisso... Resolveu